# directive Isolated Scope undefined, angularjs 1.3

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I'm doing a directive I have a strange behavior when I do a console over the **scope** I get a value passed from the controller scope printed, but when I try to access it from the scope is undefined like **scope.model**

this is the code:

```
function() {
        var color = d3.interpolateRgb('#f77', '#77f');  
        return {
            template: '<div></div>',
            restrict: 'E',
            scope:{
                model:'='
            },
            link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

                console.log(scope); //print model
                console.log('scope.model ',scope.model); // undefined

                var width = attrs.width || 940,
                    height = attrs.height || 500,
                    margin = 20;

                var modeler = d3.select(element[0])
                    .append('svg')
                    .attr('width', width)
                    .attr('height', height);

            }
        };
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<d3-directive model="model" width="920" height="510" ></d3-directive>
```

Please take a look to the console output:
[image: console output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up by adding a $watch over value of the scope and using the new value assigned.

```
return {
        template: '<div></div>',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
            model:'='
        },
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

            console.log(scope); 
            console.log('scope.model ',scope.model);

            scope.$watch('model',function(newValue,oldValue){
                if(!!newValue){
                    console.log(newValue);
                }
            });

            var width = attrs.width || 940,
                height = attrs.height || 500,
                margin = 20;

            var modeler = d3.select(element[0])
                .append('svg')
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', height);

        }
    };
```

Comment: Have exactly the same issue. Seems using $watch is the only option